# Copying websocket payload info from chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome

How do you copy the entirety of the "frames" tab when inspecting a web socket in Chrome Developer Tools? Whenever Ctrl A, then Ctrl C, it only copies what is currently visible on my screen, not everything in the tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this annoying problem too. I will look into getting a fix for this in a future release of DevTools. In the meantime, I came up with a method of getting the data out of DevTools.

1. Open up DevTools in un-docked mode and navigate to the Frame panel.
2. Open up DevTools inspector using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Windows)

[image]

[image]

3. Inspect the Frame panel, select the `table` element, and then right-click and select Copy > Copy outerHTML

[image]

4. Paste into your text editor and save it as an HTML page.
5. Open it up in the browser to view the table, which you can copy without restriction.

[image]

### Update:

Before you Copy the contents of the HTML in step 3, you need to run the following code in the Console of the DevTools inspector (not the page one). The reason is that the rows in the table are only rendered when they are visible in the view port, based on size and scroll position. This explains a lot. The code below will override the `__calculateVisibleNodes` function to return the un-filtered list of nodes rather than reducing it to 11 items at a time.

```
WebInspector.ViewportDataGrid.prototype._calculateVisibleNodes = function() {
   return { visibleNodes: this._flatNodesList()};
}
```

**Note:** You will need to re-open DevTools again later as this change will mess with other features.

Comment: Unfortunately, copying the outer HTML only copied what was visible at the time... which is really stupid. It seems like it edits the HTML elements on the fly while scrolling. Can you double check to see if you have the same problem?

Comment: @redside100 Oh, wow I looked at the source code and it is calculating what nodes to render based on the viewport size and scroll position. I found a workaround to add to the process above. It's really annoying lol.

Comment: step 2 asks to inspect the frame element. How do you do that ? I cannot seem to be able to right click it !

Comment: I can't inspect the Frames panel. It seems inspector can only check a web page instead of a page inside dev tool

Comment: there is an open issue for this feature https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=496006, please "star" it